# custom directive coloring with sublimetext

Tags: angularjs-directive, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm working with angular.js and I'm downloaded the angularjs plugin. When I write a custom directive ex. `<product-title></product-title>` it is showing as two different colors. "product" is red then "-title" is green. Do you know how to fix it so that it is wrapped in the same color? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a work-around based on AngularJS syntax.

Use a colon instead of a dash between words. i.e.:

```
<product:title></product:title>
```

Sublime will highlight this correctly.